# How can I get ssh keys from servers using ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible, ssh-keys

I want to get all ssh public keys from servers using loop_control.loop_var. Playbook will alternately go to the home folder of all users and get the keys

I started using this construct, but then I don't know what my next steps will be.

```
tasks:
  - ansible.builtin.shell: "cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}'" 
    register: usersname # list users
      
  - ansible.builtin.shell: "cat /etc/passwd | grep '^{{ item }}' | awk -F: '{print $6}'"
    loop: "{{ usersname.stdout_lines }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the database *passwd*

```yaml
    - getent:
        database: passwd
```

and declare the below variables

```yaml
  users_all: "{{ getent_passwd.keys()|list }}"
  homes_all: "{{ getent_passwd|dict2items|map(attribute='value.4') }}"
  homes_dict_all: "{{ dict(users_all|zip(homes_all)) }}"
  homes_dict: "{{ homes_dict_all|dict2items|
                  selectattr('value', 'match', '/home')|items2dict }}"
```

Find public keys

```yaml
    - find:
        path: "{{ item.value }}/.ssh"
        patterns: '*.pub'
      register: out
      loop: "{{ homes_dict|dict2items }}"
```

and declare the dictionary

```yaml
  homes_dict_ssh: "{{ dict(out.results|
                           json_query('[].[item.key, files[].path]')) }}"
```

gives, for example

```yaml
ok: [test_11] => 
  homes_dict_ssh:
    MyUser1: []
    User1: []
    admin:
    - /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    alice: []
    bob: []
ok: [test_13] => 
  homes_dict_ssh:
    admin: []
```

Fetch the key(s) with the full path

```yaml
    - fetch:
        dest: /tmp/ansible/pk
        src: "{{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ homes_dict_ssh|dict2items|subelements('value') }}"
```

gives on the localhost

```bash
shell> tree -a  /tmp/ansible/pk 
/tmp/ansible/pk
└── test_11
    └── home
        └── admin
            └── .ssh
                └── id_rsa.pub
```

Optionally, you can strip the basenames from the public keys

```yaml
    - fetch:
        dest: "/tmp/ansible/pk/{{ inventory_hostname }}/{{ item.0.key }}/{{ item.1|basename }}"
        src: "{{ item.1 }}"
        flat: true
      loop: "{{ homes_dict_ssh|dict2items|subelements('value') }}"
```

gives on the localhost

```bash
shell> tree -a /tmp/ansible/pk
/tmp/ansible/pk
└── test_11
    └── admin
        └── id_rsa.pub
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    users_all: "{{ getent_passwd.keys()|list }}"
    homes_all: "{{ getent_passwd|dict2items|map(attribute='value.4') }}"
    homes_dict_all: "{{ dict(users_all|zip(homes_all)) }}"
    homes_dict: "{{ homes_dict_all|dict2items|
                    selectattr('value', 'match', '/home')|items2dict }}"

    homes_dict_ssh: "{{ dict(out.results|
                             json_query('[].[item.key, files[].path]')) }}"

  tasks:

    - getent:
        database: passwd
    - debug:
        var: homes_dict

    - find:
        path: "{{ item.value }}/.ssh"
        patterns: '*.pub'
      register: out
      loop: "{{ homes_dict|dict2items }}"
    - debug:
        var: out
    - debug:
       var: homes_dict_ssh

    - fetch:
        dest: /tmp/ansible/pk
        src: "{{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ homes_dict_ssh|dict2items|subelements('value') }}"
      when: not basenames|d(false)|bool

    - fetch:
        dest: "/tmp/ansible/pk/{{ inventory_hostname }}/{{ item.0.key }}/{{ item.1|basename }}"
        src: "{{ item.1 }}"
        flat: true
      loop: "{{ homes_dict_ssh|dict2items|subelements('value') }}"
      when: basenames|d(false)|bool
```